# How can I normalize a range of data in pandas where one column is categorical?

Tags: python, pandas, normalization, scaling, preprocessor

I have been trying to preprocess a set of data but due to one of the columns which has categorical values, I am not able to get the proper values.

[Data Type Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d49s.png)

After performing normalization, I am getting values in categories for the Educational Degree. 
[Normalization Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyT2p.png)

Is there any better option to deal with this or any alternate to make the result better?

Comment: Welcome to SO!... If you have some textual data, please do not include it as images, but as text instead. If you have struggle with formatting, someone may also help you with that - besides your actual problem... By the way: What is your desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will keep it in mind for future. I am expecting to have a range of scaled values that would give the values in such a way that it would not categorise the scaled values.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a list of columns you have to normalize from the dataframe.

```
cols = ['A','B']
for col in cols:
  df[col] = (df[col]-df[col].min())/(df[col].max()-df[col].min())
```